After uploading the Android target sdk and compilation sdk to 34, the error RECEVER_NOT_EXPORTED flag cannot find symbol appears when building the app
There is an error when adding the RECEVER_NOT_EXPORTED flag in the register receiver and building it.
After uploading the Android target sdk and compilation sdk to 34, the error RECEVER_NOT_EXPORTED flag cannot find symbol appears when building the app
This is my version
compileSdkVersion 34
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 34
Gradle is 7.2 version

This issue arises because RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED was introduced in Android API level 33, and your current build tools version (30.0.3) predates this addition.
Solution: Update Build Tools Version to atleast 33.0.0
Hope this helps.
